How to apply brightness to a rectangular region with a feather
I need to batch process image files and know nothing about ImageMagick, but it is installed on my mac and I can use it.  I have over 60 png files that are 256x256 pixels in size that I wish to brighten in a rectangular region with a feather applied to the edges of the region.  Can this be done in ImageMagick, and how?
Here is the original image

Here is what I want in terms of brightness, but I am unable to demonstrate feather as I am not proficient in GiMP.

I want to use a feather of about 64 pixels.
I want to brighten the rectangle with origin at 32,32 having width/height of 192x192 (ie 256 - 32 - 32), so 32,32,192x192.
I am using a Mac Mini M1 2020 running macOS Sonoma 14.5
% magick --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.10-0 Q16 x86_64 2020-03-08 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2020 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(3.1) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib freetype heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr png tiff webp xml zlib

EDIT
I've engaged ChatGPT to attempt to solve this issue.  It produces a script that runs, but the results are far from intended.  Here is the script and resulting image.
#!/bin/zsh

# Function to show usage
function show_usage {
    echo "Usage: $0 --brightness value [--region x,y,width,height] [--feather radius] input_file"
    echo "  --brightness value            Adjust brightness (value between -1 and 1)"
    echo "  --region x,y,width,height     Apply adjustment only to the specified rectangular region"
    echo "  --feather radius              Feather (blur) the edges of the region (radius in pixels)"
    echo "  input_file                    The image file to process"
    exit 1
}

# Check that arguments are provided
if [[ $# -lt 3 ]]; then
    show_usage
fi

# Parse arguments
REGION=""
FEATHER=0
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case "$1" in
        --brightness)
            BRIGHTNESS="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        --region)
            REGION="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        --feather)
            FEATHER="$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        *)
            INPUT_FILE="$1"
            shift
            ;;
    esac
done

# Check if input file exists
if [[ ! -f "$INPUT_FILE" ]]; then
    echo "Input file does not exist: $INPUT_FILE"
    exit 1
fi

# Calculate the brightness adjustment percentage for ImageMagick
BRIGHTNESS_PERCENT=$(echo "scale=2; (1 + $BRIGHTNESS) * 100" | bc)

# Create an output filename
OUTPUT_FILE="${INPUT_FILE%.*}_brightness_feathered.${INPUT_FILE##*.}"

# If region is specified, apply brightness only to that region
if [[ -n "$REGION" ]]; then
    # Parse the region values
    IFS=',' read -r REGION_X REGION_Y REGION_WIDTH REGION_HEIGHT <<< "$REGION"

    echo "Applying brightness to region: ${REGION_X},${REGION_Y} ${REGION_WIDTH}x${REGION_HEIGHT}"
    echo "Feathering: ${FEATHER}px"

    magick "$INPUT_FILE" \
        \( +clone -crop "${REGION_WIDTH}x${REGION_HEIGHT}+${REGION_X}+${REGION_Y}" \
        -modulate "$BRIGHTNESS_PERCENT",100,100 -write mpr:region +delete \) \
        \( -size "${REGION_WIDTH}x${REGION_HEIGHT}" xc:black -fill white \
        -draw "rectangle 0,0 ${REGION_WIDTH},${REGION_HEIGHT}" \
        -blur 0x"$FEATHER" -write mpr:mask +delete \) \
        "$INPUT_FILE" -write mpr:original \
        \( mpr:region mpr:mask -compose DstIn -composite \) \
        -geometry +${REGION_X}+${REGION_Y} -compose Over -composite "$OUTPUT_FILE"

else
    # Apply brightness adjustment to the entire image
    magick "$INPUT_FILE" -modulate "$BRIGHTNESS_PERCENT",100,100 "$OUTPUT_FILE"
fi

# Output result
echo "Brightness adjusted image saved as: $OUTPUT_FILE"


I used the following command:
% script.sh --brightness 0.6 --region 64,64,224,224 --feather 10 sample-1.png


It can be done. But may not be as simple as you might like.  Please post and example input and what you expect for the output. Provide what rectangle (x,y,w,h) in the image you need processed. Also how much feather distance you want.  Also what is your Imagemagick version and what is your platform/OS?

Please read the information guides in the help center (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - And Show Code As Text, Not An Image" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

This should do what you want in Imagemagick.

infile=image.png
wd=224
ht=224
xo=32
yo=32
brightness=0.6
feather=10
region="${wd}x${ht}+${xo}+${yo}"
brightness_pct=$(echo "scale=2; (1 + $brightness) * 100" | bc)
outfile="${infile%.*}_${brightness}_${feather}.${infile##*.}"
echo "$region"
echo "$brightness_pct"
echo "$outfile"

magick "$infile" +repage \
\( +clone -crop "$region" -modulate "$brightness_pct",100,100 \) \
\( -size "$region" xc:black -fill white -draw "rectangle 0,0 $wd,$ht" -blur 0x$feather \) \
-geometry +${xo}+${yo} -compose Over -composite "$outfile"


You can add the rest of the script commands.
ChatGPT added too much redundancy to the Imagemagick command, which messed up the command and you used different region origin from what you wanted. They used 64,64 and you actually said originally that you wanted 32,32.
ADDITION
Here is script with a for loop over all PNG images in a directory.  Change the directory and other arguments as desired
directory=/Users/fred/desktop/test
wd=224
ht=224
xo=32
yo=32
brightness=0.6
feather=10
cd
cd $directory
for infile in *.png; do
outfile="${infile%.*}_${brightness}_${feather}.${infile##*.}"
region="${wd}x${ht}+${xo}+${yo}"
brightness_pct=$(echo "scale=2; (1 + $brightness) * 100" | bc)
im7 magick "$infile" +repage \
\( +clone -crop "$region" -modulate "$brightness_pct",100,100 \) \
\( -size "$region" xc:black -fill white -draw "rectangle 0,0 $wd,$ht" -blur 0x$feather \) \
-geometry +${xo}+${yo} -compose Over -composite "$outfile"
done


This script doesn't batch process files.  It processes 1 file.  I specified in the first sentence that I need to process multiple files.

32,32 was an example.  The region location and size is arbitrary.

@andrewz I have left that to you to loop over all your images to process them. I just showed you how to do your Imagemagick processing. The rest is bash or zsh scripting. Can you not do that? You have a good reputation at 5k. Can you not modify your ChatGPT code to use my Imagmagick command? You could also create an AppleScript to process the code I gave you calling it as a bash or zsh shell script.

If you cannot do shell scripting, I will add a FOR loop over a directory in my answer. But you do not seem to be very appreciative. You write your first comment above as if you are expecting someone to write your code for you. That is not what StackOverflow is for. It is here to help debug code. I debugged your Imagemagick code. That is my expertise. I do not see any looping over your images in your ChatGPT code, so I just simplified it and fixed the Imagemagick part. Sorry, but I thought that would be enough and that you would be able to add the FOR loop, yourself.

@andrewz See my ADDITION in my answer. I have posted code that loops over a directory. Change the directory to where ever you want.
